# How can I tell whether or not a processor supports Nested Page Tables (AMD) or Extended Page Tables (Intel)?

Tags: cpu, virtualization

Apparently doing things is hard because neither [CPU-Z nor Intel's site report whether or not this is supported](https://superuser.com/questions/286937/what-features-should-i-look-for-in-a-laptop-for-virtualization-heavy-workloads/286941#286941), which seems strange to me.

So.. if I'm in a position where I can't just go to the laptop and install a virtualization package to check (e.g. the best I can do is run something from a USB key), how can I tell if a CPU has this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly [CoreInfo can now check for second level address translation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722)!

Comment: Note that you must pass `-v` to it. Works though! +1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware this doesn't directly answer your question (it's not a test), but for Intel, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Page_Table):

> Intel states that the feature is available in all their Nehalem-based CPUs with virtualization support; namely in Core i7, Core i5, Core i3, Pentium G6950 and appropriate Xeons.
>
> It is not available in Core 2-based and earlier Intel CPUs.

Comment: OK, this works for Intel. (+1) AMD?

Answer (score -1):

I know that VirtualBox won't let you check the "Enable Nested Paging" for a virtual setting if it isn't supported. You may want to read this:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_Page_Tables

Comment: I would +1 this except doing this is explicitly disallowed in the body of the question. ;)

Comment: @Billy: I really want to -1 this, lol, knowing where you're coming from...

Comment: Hey, I did look into this.. even looked up CPU commands (in linux cause thats what I'm running) to see if potentially there were processor flags that are set to say that that feature is allowed.. But from what I saw there was no such flag that is easily read. So that was out. CPU-Z is the only other cpu app for Windows that I know. And the link I posted has: "The Intel equivalent, called Extended Page Tables was introduced in the Nehalem architecture"... Should answer the question.... Just defending my answer.

Comment: So with the information I provided, the asker could see what processor they have installed (with CPU-Z) and look up an Intel CPU timeline (such as: http://www.intel.com/pressroom/kits/quickrefyr.htm) and be able to tell if theirs is new enough to have it.