# Many programs do not respond for a while after memory and SSD upgrade

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, freeze

A few months ago I installed an SSD and memory on my notebook. I also started using Windows 8 and started having many programs going into 'Not Responding' state for a while (sometimes up to a minute) then continue without a problem. At first I thought the problem was Windows 8 and installed the drivers manually. It didn't help.

I ignored it for a while, but then it became frustrating. Today I went back to Windows 7. As you can guess, the problem continues, and I have no idea what is causing it.

- I had installed all updates in both Windows versions.
- I replaced two 1GB chips with 2GB ones(same mhz)
- It's a [Dell Inspiron 1520](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/laptops/125460/dell-inspiron-1520/specifications)

Any idea why would it happen? How can I diagnose this problem?

**Update**

- SSD is an [Intel 330 Series 120 GB](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-330-series.html).
- I did not update SSD firmware.
- I have not disabled LPM (I am going to try it now).

Comment: What's the SSD? I remember early models ultimately failed after some (millions) of read-write cycles.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/253961/why-does-my-windows-7-pc-ssd-drive-keep-freezing) article answers your question.

Comment: Have you upgraded the firmware on your SSD?

Comment: disable *Link Power Management (LPM)* which can cause freezes.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I have updated the post.

Comment: @cybernard I have updated the post.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have updated the post.

Comment: @user73983  Updating the firmware is critical to its correct function. Go here NOW!!!!  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455

Comment: @cybernard SSD Toolbox says "The selected Intel SSD contains current firmware as of this Toolbox release. Click Check For Updates to look for a newer version of the Intel SSD Toolbox, which may include newer firmware."

Comment: @user73983  Try chkdsk /r c: from the administrative command prompt.  Otherwise we might just have to use Eraser to zero out all of the unused sectors.

Comment: have you tried to disable Link Power Management (LPM)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SSD was the problem. I have tried many suggestions online to fix this issue but none of them worked. I sent it to the support and they replaced it.